# Gem's for pick date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new in rails and wanted to ask next question - how work with dates in reils?
For example I have to ask the user's date of birth.
Are there any special gems for this? (Just in standard, you can choose February 31 and it will be the norm ...)

Answer (score 1):

Ryan bates also has a great railcast on the subject. Paying for the pro episodes is well worth it!

http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars

Answer (score 0):

Try `date_select`.  Or if you like JS, you can try `jqueryui`'s `datepicker`.

Welcome to Rails and to stackoverflow!